# Calling my API Key from server side and declaring it a global variable on client side

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, global-variables

I am trying to hide my paystack API key from being editable on the client side. I have JSON string it but it just won't work. The paystack function doesn't recognize the data received. I hope someone can put me through on this. Below are the client and server side codes. I hope to also learn how to parse a global variable to client side the correct way.

CLIENT SIDE JS

```
<script>

const paymentForm = document.getElementById('paymentForm');
function getPaystackKey(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(payWithPaystack, data => {
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
    const liveKey = parsedData.values.liveKey
    const testKey = parsedData.values.testKey
    const tester = parsedData.tester
  }).withFailureHandler(er => {
    // alert("fail")
    //alert(er)
  }).getDataFromSpreadsheet()
    //do onload work
}
if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('submit',payWithPaystack,false); //W3C
} else {
    window.attachEvent('onload',payWithPaystack); //IE
}

function payWithPaystack(e, parsedData) {
  e.preventDefault();
    const liveKey = parsedData.values.liveKey
    const testKey = parsedData.values.testKey
    const tester = parsedData.tester

  let handler = PaystackPop.setup({
    key: testKey // Replace with your public key
    email: document.getElementById("email").value,
    amount: document.getElementById("totalAmount").value * 100,
    ref: document.getElementById("reference").value,
    //ref: ''+Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1), // generates a pseudo-unique reference. Please replace with a reference you generated. Or remove the line entirely so our API will generate one for you
    // label: "Optional string that replaces customer email"
    onClose: function(){
      alert('Window closed.');
      document.getElementById("paymentForm").reset();
    },
    callback: function(response){
      let message = 'Payment complete! Reference: ' + response.reference;
      alert(message);
      document.getElementById("paymentForm").reset();
    }
  });

  handler.openIframe();
}

</script>
```

SERVER SIDE JS

```
function getDataFromSpreadsheet(){
  const ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("PRIVATE");
  const liveKey = ws.getRange("A2").getValue()
  const testKey = ws.getRange("B2").getValue()
  const tester = "'pk_test_70366345d1f9ef32f81b6449'"
  Logger.log(tester);

  return JSON.stringify({tester: tester ,values: {liveKey: liveKey, testKey: testKey}})
};
```

Comment: In your situation, how is your script `getPaystackKey()` run? From your question, I couldn't understand it. I apologize for this.

Comment: oh that fuction runs from the client side. I have edited the code as i should have added the script tag

Comment: I am looking to pass those variable from the getDataFromSpreadsheet fuction on the server side and use it in the payWithPaystack function on the client side.

The getPaystackKey gets the data from the server side using the google.script.run function. I hope i am able to make you understand. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand how you run `getPaystackKey()`. But, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: Uhm okay getPaystackKey() runs when the submit event is fired by user. It gets three keys from the server side function getDataFromSpreadsheet() and return (liveKey, testKey and tester). However i only need one of those key in the payWithPaystack() function that runs after the Parsed data has been received from the server. My problem is that i am unable to use the parsed data in the payWithPaystack() function. 

+ your English is not bad at all !

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the detail of the relationship between `getPaystackKey()` and `payWithPaystack(e, parsedData)`? And, in your situation, the function `payWithPaystack(e, parsedData)` is run independently without executing`getPaystackKey()`?

Comment: No, the payWithPaystack(e, parsedData) function runs after getPaystackKey() has gotten the Parseddata from the server side getDataFromSpreadsheet() function. I hope you are able to understand now?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `the payWithPaystack(e, parsedData) function runs after getPaystackKey() has gotten the Parseddata from the server side getDataFromSpreadsheet() function.`, when I saw your script, it seems that after `getPaystackKey()` was run, `payWithPaystack(e, parsedData)` is not run. So, I cannot still understand your situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: Yes I also thought that was where the hold up was, I’m not sure on what to do really. I’m still searching for solutions.